# jQuery element ID changing causes mistake

Tags: jquery, html

I've got 4 divs with the ids `#registrieren`, `#story`, `#faq` and `#mediadaten`, and this jQuery script:

```
var menu='';
$(function()
{
    $('#registrieren').attr('id', 'menuAktiv');
    menu='registrieren';

    $('#registrieren').click(function()
    {
        if(menu != 'registrieren')
        {
            $('#menuAktiv').attr('id', menu);
            $('#registrieren').attr('id', 'menuAktiv');
            menu='registrieren';
        }
        alert(menu);
    });
    $('#story').click(function()
    {
    if(menu!='story')
    {
        $('#menuAktiv').attr('id', menu);
        $('#story').attr('id', 'menuAktiv');
        menu='story';
        }
        alert(menu);
    });
    $('#faq').click(function()
    {
        if(menu != 'faq')
        {
            $('#menuAktiv').attr('id', menu);
            $('#faq').attr('id', 'menuAktiv');
            menu='faq';
        }
        alert(menu);
    });
    $('#mediadaten').click(function()
    {
        if(menu != 'mediadaten')
        {
            $('#menuAktiv').attr('id', menu);
            $('#mediadaten').attr('id', 'menuAktiv');
            menu='mediadaten';
        }
        alert(menu);
    });
});
```

now, when I'm clicking on `#story`, `#faq` or `#mediadaten` I'm not able to change the id of `#registrieren` back to `#menuAktiv`.

The same problem happens when I'm changing another element id of those elements in the beginning. Any solutions?

Comment: Why do you need to change an element's id?

Comment: You shouldn't be changing an element's id to mark it active or not, you should be adding and removing classes.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using classes instead of ids to denote which div is active.

http://api.jquery.com/addClass

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass

then use $('.classname') to select it.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than changing the id to `menuAktiv` try using a class.

```
$(function()
{
    $('#registrieren').addClass('menuAktiv');

    // attach a click to all items
    $('#registrieren,#story,#faq,#mediadaten').click(function()
    {
        if ($(this).is(".menuAktiv"))
            return false;

        // remove current active menu class
        $('.menuAktiv').removeClass('menuAktiv');

        // set active class to clicked item
        $(this).addClass('menuAktiv');
    });
});​
```

This can probably be even more optimized if I saw your markup

---

**working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/XMu9n/**

Answer (score 3):

From your code it seems that you're trying to make something active with your `id=menuAktiv`.

Then to do this you can use `class=menuAktiv`.

***Code:***

```
$('#registrieren').addClass('menuAktiv'); // initially set active 
                                               // class to registrieren
```

then on click on any one change that class. For example:

```
$('#registrieren, #store, #faq, #mediadaten').click( function() {
  $('.menuAktiv').removeClass('menuAktiv'); // remove active class
  $(this).addClass('menuAktiv'); // add active class to clicked item
});
```

---

#### More

Better would be if you make a generic function for this. For example:

```
function changeActiveElement(el) {
   $('.menuAktiv').removeClass('menuAktiv'); // remove active class
   $(el).addClass('menuAktiv'); // add active class to clicked item
}
```

And now call this function from click handler like below:

```
$('#registrieren, #store, #faq, #mediadaten').click( function() {
   changeActiveElement(this);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem comes from the first few lines.

```
 $('#registrieren').attr('id', 'menuAktiv');
menu='registrieren';

$('#registrieren').click(function()
{
    if(menu != 'registrieren')
    {
        $('#menuAktiv').attr('id', menu);
        $('#registrieren').attr('id', 'menuAktiv');
        menu='registrieren';
    }
    alert(menu);
});
```

In the third line, $('#registrieren') points to nothing. $('#registrieren') searches the dom for the element with id="registrieren". Well, since you've changed that element's id to something else, $('#registrieren') wont give you nothing.

To make it work (not necessarily the best approach to do what your code is trying to do though), and to prove that what I just described is actually happening, what you could do is  save a reference to that element in a variable (pre-change). Then in the future you'd use that anytime you wanted to target the element.

```
var registrieren = $('#registrieren');

registrieren.attr('id', 'menuAktiv');

registrieren.click(function() {
//etc
});
```

As for using classes instead of ids to 'change states', yes, that's probably a much better idea - no need to keep saving references to previous ids.

Comment: I don't really understand the downvote - the reason for why it's not working is explained.